# Frontend - Validate form without submit

Tags: magento-2.0, frontend, validation

I have this template.

```
<div class="estimate">    
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" name="text" required>
    </form>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="calculate-btn" class="button">Calculate</a>
</div>
```

I want to validate text input after clicking to the **Calculate** button. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<script>
    requirejs([
        'jquery',
        'jquery/validation'
    ], function($) {
        $("a#estimate-calculate-btn").on("click", function () {
            $("#form1").validate();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please help me through this problem.

And if there is any extra information needed, please tell me.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Try this One, I hope this is usefull for you.. I think syntax error in script.

```
      <script>
        requirejs([
            'jquery',
            'jquery/validation'
        ], function ($) {
            //Your code lines should be here   
            $("a#estimate-calculate-btn").on("click", function () {
                $("#form1").validate();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, but it still didn't work.